# Installing PyQt4 for Python3

Tags: 11.04, python, pyqt

I am trying to get my code running using Python3 and PyQt4. When I do this:

```
gruszczy@gruszczy-laptop:~/Programy/fathom/tools$ python3.1 fathomqt.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fathomqt.py", line 5, in <module>
    from PyQt4.QtCore import (QFileSystemModel, QDir, SIGNAL, Qt)
ImportError: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sip.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_CompareWithASCIIString
```

I have installed Sip and PyQt4 by hand in both `/usr/lib/python3/dist-utils` and `/usr/lib/python3.1/dist-packages`, but neither helped.

I have `libpython3.1` as well as `python3.1-dev` and both packages for `3.2` either. What am I missing?

I am using `Natty` beta, but I don't believe this is a problem, since it's now quite stable on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-qt4/+bug/400826).

Basically, you will need to compile pyqt yourself because using running the packaged pyqt with python 3 is not supported yet, not even in Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty).

Python 3 support for Gnome and KDE is a priority for Ubuntu 11.10 so maybe later this year, it will be working better.

However, there may be something specifically wrong since you said that you did try installing from source. Perhaps installing the packaged sip might help. Maybe, this [email](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2011-April/033049.html) relates to your issue. I think you should open a Ubuntu bug about this.

Comment: That's strange. It seems that it is Natty's fault after all. I managed to install it PyQt from source without any problems under Maverick.

Comment: No, it's not Natty's fault. Ubuntu has yet to fully integrate Python 3 so this has been an issue for several releases now.

Comment: I am talking about something else. I have no problem installing Sip and PyQt4 from source (I downloaded it from riverbank) and it worked under Maverick. I did the same trick under Natty and it didn't work.